# My assets are not linked in my twig files in production only

Tags: reactjs, symfony, twig, vite, cdn

I am currently migrating my app from **Webpack to Vite**.

My app is using React & Symfony.

So i followed [vite-bundle](https://github.com/lhapaipai/vite-bundle) and [vite-symfony-plugin](https://github.com/lhapaipai/vite-plugin-symfony) instructions. Everything is working perfectly fine in dev server/locally, but i have issues when i am pushing to my Review App.

My twig are rendered without any `<script>` or `<link>` from my `vite_entry_..._tag`.

My assets are uploaded in a CDN.

Do you have any ideas how can i fix that ? Thank you.

Here is my `vite.config.js` :

```js
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());

  return {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        // ...
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      react(),
      symfonyPlugin({
        /* defaultValues */
        servePublic: true,
        refresh: true,
        /** If you set server.host: '0.0.0.0' in your vite.config.js
         * you have to set 'localhost' */
        viteDevServerHostname: null,
      }),
    ],
    base: `${env.VITE_PATH_ASSET || ''}/build`,
    build: {
      outDir: './public/build',
      manifest: true,
      rollupOptions: {
        input: {
          // ...
        },
      },
    },
    server: {
      origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
    },
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if twig functions return is empty, this means there is a problem with the entry points.
You can try to make exceptions more verbose with

```yaml
# config/packages/pentatrion_vite.yaml
pentatrion_vite:
  throw_on_missing_entry: true
```

else look at your `public/build/entrypoints.json` maybe you can found informations ?

```js
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig(({mode }) => {
  return {
    plugins: [
      symfonyPlugin(),
    ],
  
    base: mode === 'development' ? '/build/' : 'http://cdn.domain.com/build/',
  
    build: {
      outDir: './public/build', 
      manifest: true,
      rollupOptions: {
        input: {
          "app": "./assets/app.js",
        }
      },
    },
  }
});
```

else, open a discussion in https://github.com/lhapaipai/vite-bundle with a step by step to reproduce your error :-)